# Bash to send variable value to csv?

Tags: text-processing, csv

I've the following data. I've only given 2 servers here for the sake of simplicity. This servers list might be change from time to time, the same goes with the variable value.

```
hostname = 'server1'
var1 = 'abc'
var2 = 'xyz'
var3 = 'def'

hostname = 'server7'
var1 = 'ghi'
var2 = 'mno'
var3 = 'jkl'
```

Would it be possible to send it to csv format, probably something like this?

output.csv

```
Hostname    Variable    Value
server1     var1        abc
server1     var2        xyz
server1     var3        def
server7     var1        ghi
server7     var2        mno
server7     var3        jkl
```

At the moment, I copy paste the value manually to Ms Excel. I would like to automate this process, but not sure about the implementation yet.

I really appreciate if you could share some ideas or sample code.

Comment: The answer is yes, but the implementation depends on the tools you want to use. Can you edit your post to show what you already tried, so that we understand what you would consider viable/what tools can be used?

Comment: Thanks @AdminBee, I'm not sure about the implementation yet. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is that the exact format of your input data? Or are you just showing us the variables and values?

Comment: Did you try this way https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/650724/195582 ?

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F"[=' ]" -v OFS=, '
$1=="hostname"{ hn=$5; next }
!hdr && hn    { print "Hostname", "Variable", "Value"; hdr=1 }
NF   && hn    { print hn, $1, $5 }' infile >output.csv
```

with `-F"[=' ]"`, we defined either of `=`, `'` and Space characters as the field separators, so awk will split the lines to the fields based on these separators.

with `OFS=,`, the output generates in comma delimited fields to produce a simple csv file, change this to some other characters based on your need.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
<input.txt sed "s/'//g" | mlr --x2c --ips "=" clean-whitespace then reshape -r "var" -o variable,value
```

you will have

```
hostname,variable,value
server1,var1,abc
server1,var2,xyz
server1,var3,def
server7,var1,ghi
server7,var2,mno
server7,var3,jkl
```

If you additionally want to do the removal of the single quotes conditional on them existing only at the start and end of a field's value, and if you want the upper-case field names:

```
mlr --x2c --ips = clean-whitespace then reshape -r '^var' -o Variable,Value then put 'for (k,v in $*) { $[k]=sub(v,"^'\''(.*)'\''$","\1") }' then label Hostname input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty the same as @αғsнιη.
I use a `BEGIN` block to write the header and an assignement `$0 = ""` ot empty the line when this hold the server name.

```
awk -F"[= ']" -vOFS=, 'BEGIN {print "Hostname", "Variable", "Value"} $5~/^server[0-9]+$/ && h=$5 {$0 = ""} $0!~/^$/ {print h, $1, $5}' data
```